# C# LoadLibrary returns zero if Visual Studio not installed

Tags: c#

In a C# program I dynamically load a C++ dll. I use DllImport( "kernel32.dll" ) to be able to call LoadLibrary(). I run this program on two PC's, both are Windows10 64bit. On one PC the Visual Studio software is installed on the other not. Program works fine on the PC with VS but LoadLibrary(foo.dll) returns zero on the one without VS. LastWin32Error is zero. I don't have any exception. The dll is in the same folder with the executable. I use as parameter for LoadLibrary() just dll name, no absolute or relative path (as a matter fact I also tried full path name with same result). On the PC with VS, program works not only if I started from VS environment but also if I simply launch the executable. What's the secret? How do I debug this?
Thanks

Comment: Use `depends`, these days available from http://www.dependencywalker.com/, to see what dependencies the native DLL has. My guess is that you're missing an appropriate version of the C++ runtime, possibly the debug one.

Comment: Agree with cynic. The Debug C++ RunTime is used with Visual Studio, and is _not_ redistributable. The root cause would be that foo.dll has been built in debug mode.

Comment: that's right, dll was built in debug mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My instinct would be that a dependency cannot be found - some other file that the DLL relies upon.

To track that down, I'd use a tool such as [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to see all of the file system accesses that happen whilst the `LoadLibrary` call is running.

Comment: I used DependencyWalker and it shows numberless dependencies missing, hard to tell which one is critical. As a matter fact, also on the PC where it works, Dependency Walker shows numberless dependencies missing.

Comment: @SilviuP - I didn't suggest Dependency Walker - I suggested Process Monitor. That lets you see what's happening at runtime. For each dependency, you'll see it probe for it in a number of locations but the key thing to bear in mind is that the current *critical* dependency is likely to be the *last* file it probed for before it failed the `LoadLibrary` call.